# Understanding just what is an image

Tags: image-processing

I suppose the simplest understanding of what a (bitmap) image is would be an array of pixels. After that, it gets pretty technical.

I've been trying to understand the sort of information that an image may provide and have come across a large collection of technical terms like "mipmap", "pitch", "stride", "linear", "depth", as well as other format-specific things.

These seem to pop up across a lot of different formats so it'd probably be useful to understand what purpose they serve in an image. Looking at the DDS, BMP, PNG, TGA, JPG documentations has only made it clear that an image is pretty confusing.

Though searching around for some hours, there wasn't any nice tutorial-like break-down of just what an image is and all of the different properties.

The eventual goal would be to take proprietary image formats and convert them to more common formats like DDS or BMP. Or to make up some image format.

Any good readings?

Answer (score 1):

Even your simplified explanation of an image doesn't encompass all the possibilities. For example an image can be divided by planes, where the red pixel values are all together followed by the green pixel values, followed by the blue pixel values. Such layouts are uncommon but still possible.

Assuming a simple layout of pixels you must still determine the pixel format. You might have a paletted image where some number of bits (1, 4, or 8) will be an index into a palette or color table which will define the RGB color of the pixel along with the transparency of the pixel (one index will typically be reserved as a transparent pixel). Otherwise the pixel will be 3 or 4 bytes depending on whether a transparency or alpha value is included. The order of the values (R,G,B) or (B,G,R) will depend on the format - Windows bitmaps are B,G,R while everything else will most likely be R,G,B.

The stride is the number of bytes between rows of the image. Windows bitmaps for example will take the width of the image times the number of bytes per pixel and round it up to the next multiple of 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of DDA, and BMP is only common in the Windows world (and there's a lot more computing in the non-windows world than you might think). Rather than worry about all of the technical details of this, why not just use an existing toolkit such as image magick, which can already batch convert from dozens of formats to your one common format?

Unless you're doing specialized work, where you would need something fancy like hdr (which most image formats don't even support -- so most of your sources would not have it in the first place), you're probably best off picking something standard like PNG or JPG. They both have plusses and minuses. You might want to support both of those depending on the image.